# How to replace Filter Origin in this PowerShell command with Windows Firewall's display name?

Tags: powershell, windows-11, windows-firewall, event-viewer, powershell-7.3

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName="Security"; Id=5152; } | ? { $_.Message -like "*Outbound*" -and -not($_.message -like "*ICMP*")} | select Message | ft -wrap
```

Found that in [here](https://www.xf.is/2022/12/05/blocking-living-of-the-land-binaries-lolbins-with-windows-firewall/), after running it, the results look like this:

[image]

filter origin has this ID which is Firewall's unique name but I want to see a more user friendly name so I can understand immediately which Firewall rule, based on its display name that I set, blocked this connection.

Update:
I want to do something like this. but it doesn't work like this and I need help fixing it. basically, **I want to keep the same output format that the original script shows** and only replace things like this `{a42a62ec-83d9-4ab5-9d54-4dbd20cfab17}` with their display name.

```
$data = (Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName="Security"; Id=5152; } |
 ? { $_.Message -like "*Outbound*" -and -not($_.message -like "*ICMP*")}).message


 $data -replace "(?<=Filter Origin:[^{]+){.+?}",{(Get-NetFirewallRule -Name $Matches[0]).DisplayName}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-with-a-script-block

Comment: know if any PS cmdlet that returns the friendly name by that string? If so, you can just replace it with some regex.

Comment: You can do `$xml = $_.toxml()` and then `$xml.event.eventdata.data` has all the named data fields.

Comment: @js2010 could you please elaborate more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a quick google search and saw [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/filter-origin-documentation) on troubleshooting firewalls, and it points to [`Get-NetFireWallRule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/get-netfirewallrule?view=windowsserver2022-ps) being able to get the display name from the ID. That said, you can use some handy RegEx of `(?<=Filter Origin:[^{]+){.+?}` to get the unique ID and query its friendly name:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName="Security"; Id=5152; } |
    ? { $_.Message -like "*Outbound*" -and $_.Message -notlike "*ICMP*" } | 
    Select TimeCreated, @{
        Name = 'Msg'
        Expression = {
            if ($_.Message -match ($pattern = '(?<=Filter Origin:[^{]+){.+?}'))
            {
                $_.Message -replace $pattern, (Get-NetFirewallRule -Name $Matches[0]).DisplayName
            }
            else
            {
                $_.Message
            }
        }
    } | Ft -Wrap
```

Placing it inside an if statement allows it to leave the message alone if no match was found for patterns that may be the unique ID. See [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/oCOcjz/1) for more info on the pattern itself.

Comment: Have you tried this solution yourself?
for me it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/xkDBGIt.png

Comment: Nah, I dont have your event type. Was going based of PS logic. Just expand the property otherwise to see the rest of the message

Comment: How can I expand the property?

Comment: Using `-ExpandProperty`, or *dot notation*. If you only care about the message, a `Foreach-Object` might be better in this case. See updated code.

Comment: Thank you, that did it, also used `ForEach-Object -Parallel` and that made the execution time ~3 seconds shorter from 8 seconds.

Comment: umm if I wanted to add another property like `TimeCreated` in addition to the message that is already being displayed, how would I do that? in the original script, I modified it and looks like this `Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName="Security"; Id=5152; } |  ? { $_.Message -like "*Outbound*" -and -not($_.message -like "*ICMP*")} |   Select-Object -Property TimeCreated, Message  | ft -wrap`

Comment: Using the calculated property I had at first would have allowed you to select another object as well. You would just need to format it accordingly. If you revert it back, just add the time created property and pipe to ft like you're currently doing

Comment: I edited the code again

Comment: That's perfect, appreciate that!

Answer (score 1):

You can turn events into xml and access each field seperately.  I don't have your exact event type.

```
$a = Get-WinEvent @{ LogName='Security' } -maxevents 1
$xml = [xml]$a.toxml()


$xml.event.eventdata.data

Name              #text
----              -----
SubjectUserSid    S-1-5-19
SubjectUserName   LOCAL SERVICE
SubjectDomainName NT AUTHORITY
SubjectLogonId    0x3e5
PreviousTime      2023-01-03T14:40:58.3894712Z
NewTime           2023-01-03T14:40:58.3975397Z
ProcessId         0x59c
ProcessName       C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe


$xml.event.eventdata.data | ? name -eq processname | % '#text'

C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
```

```
Get-WinEvent @{ LogName='Security' } | % { $xml = [xml]$_.toxml()
  $xml.event.eventdata.data | ? name -eq 'processname' | % '#text' }
```

Comment: You can get the exact event type by enabling auditing from the link in the question, takes 1 minute. lots of problems with your code... 1) it outputs 1 random event each time i run it 2) it shows `Direction   %%14592` instead of saying inbound or outbound 3) I added `;Id=5152` to it and didn't fix it and setting `-maxevents 1` to anything other than 1 throws an error: `$xml = [xml]$a.toxml()
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node."`

Comment: The -maxevents 1 is only meant to be an example.  You should be able to do this within a foreach-object loop.  The Direction part is unfortunate.  Some kind of extra processing would be needed.  I tried the auditing but nothing came up yet.

Comment: Thank you, upvoted, I'll try to make it work as an alternative method.

Comment: I think %%14592 means inbound and %%14593 means outbound.

Comment: Yes, you're right, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-5157