# How to convert Event Viewer data to XML for filtration and get rid of DocumentElement node error?

Tags: xml, powershell, windows-11, event-viewer

There was an answer posted here to one of my questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74994896/20682592

the code is this:

```
$a = Get-WinEvent @{ LogName='Security' } -maxevents 1
$xml = [xml]$a.toxml()


$xml.event.eventdata.data
```

what I want to do is to show all the events in the Security log with ID 5152 and then filter out the output of it based on filter origin value.

so I changed it to this:

```
$a = Get-WinEvent @{ LogName='Security'; Id=5152; }

$xml = [xml]$a.toxml()

$xml.event.eventdata.data | Where-Object {$_.FilterOrigin -ne "Stealth"}
```

but it doesn't work like I want, doesn't filter out events whose filterOrigin is Stealth and also gives me this error:

```
InvalidArgument: untitled:Untitled-3:3:1
Line |
   3 |  $xml = [xml]$a.toxml()
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node."
```

[image]

the original answer posted in there also shows the same error if I remove `-maxevents 1` which I need to do because I don't want to only see 1 event.

how can I make it work?

**Update**, using [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) comment, I managed to do this:

```
foreach ($event in (Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';ID=5152})) {
     $xml = [xml]$event.toxml(); 

     $xml.event.eventdata.data | Where-Object {$_.FilterOrigin -ne "Stealth" -or $_.FilterOrigin -ne "Unknown" } | ft -wrap

}
```

but it's not filtering out FilterOrigins Stealth and Unknown. what am i missing here?

[image]

Comment: "FilterOrigin" does not appear to be a data field in that event: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-5152

Comment: You need to loop over the events returned `foreach ($event in (Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';ID=5152})) { $xml = [xml]$event.toxml(); ... }`

Comment: @Theo please see the updated answer, the filtering isn't being applied even though when I was adding it PowerShell was auto-completing it the `filterorigin` part.

Comment: Take out the `.Name`

Comment: I tried but still Stealth and Unknown show up in the result

Comment: Still the same.. i also tried changing `-ne` to `-notlike` and added `*` around each of them but still didn't filter them out.

Comment: Try `$_.FilterOrigin -notmatch 'stealth|unknown '`

Comment: Nope, didn't help.

Comment: Sorry, meant `$_.FilterOrigin.'#text' -notmatch 'stealth|unknown '`

Comment: There's no filterorigin property, it's just name and '#text'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the name/#text pairs to be an object instead, here's a way to convert it.  I'm using the where-object form without the curly braces.  The -notmatch regex expression pipe symbol means "or".  This way you can treat all the data as one group.

```
foreach ($event in Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security'}) {
  $xml = [xml]$event.toxml();
  $xml.event.eventdata.data | 
  foreach { $hash = @{} } { $hash[$_.name] = $_.'#text' } { [pscustomobject]$hash } |
  Where FilterOrigin -notmatch 'stealth|unknown|query user|default' 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but could you add some explanation like if i wanted to expand the `-notmatch`, how would I do that? I tried `Where FilterOrigin -notmatch ('stealth','unknown','Query User Default') ` and `Where {FilterOrigin -notmatch 'stealth' -or FilterOrigin -notmatch 'unknown' -or FilterOrigin -notmatch 'Query User Default' }` but got errors.

Comment: It's a regex seperated by "or" pipe symbols, assuming all those things come under filterorigin `where filterorigin -notmatch 'stealth|unknown|query user|default'`  I'm using the form without the curly braces.