# How to replace only specific strings in PowerShell custom object?

Tags: powershell, hashtable, windows-firewall, event-viewer, pscustomobject

This is the base code:

```
 foreach ($event in Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';ID=5152}) {
    $xml = [xml]$event.toxml();
    $xml.event.eventdata.data | 
    foreach { $hash = @{} } { $hash[$_.name] = $_.'#text' } { [pscustomobject]$hash } |
    Where FilterOrigin -notmatch 'stealth|unknown|Query User Default' 
  }
```

the output is this:

[image]

**I want to replace FilterOrigin with Firewall Display name, direction with either inbound or outbound and protocol with [correct name from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-5157)**.

I just need to know how to do one or two of them, then I can do the rest myself once I know the syntax/pattern.

starting with FilterOrigin, I tried this:

```
foreach ($event in Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';ID=5152}) {
    $xml = [xml]$event.toxml();
    $xml.event.eventdata.data | 
    foreach { $hash = @{} } { $hash[$_.name] = $_.'#text' } { [pscustomobject]$hash } |
    Where FilterOrigin -notmatch 'stealth|unknown|Query User Default' | ForEach-Object {

    if ($_.filterorigin -match ($pattern = '{.+?}'))

    {
    $_.filterorigin -replace $pattern, (Get-NetFirewallRule -Name $Matches[0]).DisplayName

    }

    }
  }
```

But the output is only the Firewall `displaynames`, so it does recognize the Firewall name (which is the ID you see in the `FilterOrigin`) but doesn't replace it inside the object.

for Protocol, let's say I only want to replace `TCP (6)` and `UDP (17)`, how should I do that?

for Direction, `%%14592` is for inbound and `%%14593` is for outbound

**UPDATE:**

```
foreach ($event in Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';ID=5152}) {
    $xml = [xml]$event.toxml();
    $xml.event.eventdata.data | 
    foreach { $hash = @{} } { $hash[$_.name] = $_.'#text' } { [pscustomobject]$hash } |
    Where FilterOrigin -notmatch 'Stealth|Unknown|Query User Default|WSH Default' | ForEach-Object {

        $pattern = '\{.+?\}'
        $_.FilterOrigin =  $_.FilterOrigin -replace $pattern, (Get-NetFirewallRule -Name $Matches[0]).DisplayName


        $protocolName = @{ 6 = 'TCP'; 17 = 'UDP' }[$_.Protocol]
        $_.Protocol =  if (-not $protocolName) { $_.Protocol } else { $protocolName }



        # Conceptually clearer PowerShell (Core) 7+ alternative:
        $_.Direction = $_.Direction -eq '%%14592' ? 'Outbound' : 'Inbound'
        # $_.Direction = ('Outbound', 'Inbound')[$_.Direction -eq '%%14592']


        $_



    }
  }
```

So with this script, there are few problems,

1. the protocol isn't replaced, still the numbers are displayed
2. FilterOrigin shows up empty
3. there is a constant error after each result

[image]

in the picture, only the direction is being applied correctly.
the filter that blocked the connection shown in the script has a name but it's name not showing up.

Comment: As an aside: while `'{.+?}'` technically works, because what's between `{` and `}` happens not to be a valid quantifier, it's best to signal the intent to use these metacharacters _literally_ explicitly, by ``\``-escaping them: ``'\{.+?\}'``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the exception of `++` and `--` (and compound assignments such as `+=`, ...) PowerShell's operator do *not* perform *in-place* updates - instead they *return* (output) a result.

The [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator is no exception, so for in-place updating you must assign the result of the operation back to the input variable:

```bash
$_.FilterOrigin = 
  $_.FilterOrigin -replace $pattern, (Get-NetFirewallRule -Name $Matches[0]).DisplayName
```

---

> for Protocol, let's say I only want to replace TCP (6) and UDP (17), how should I do that?

```bash
$protocolName = @{ 6 = 'TCP'; 17 = 'UDP' }[[int] $_.Protocol]
$_.Protocol =  if (-not $protocolName) { $_.Protocol } else { $protocolName }
```

> for Direction, %%14592 is for inbound and %%14593 is for outbound

```bash
# Conceptually clearer PowerShell (Core) 7+ alternative:
#    $_.Direction = $_.Direction -eq '%%14592' ? 'Outbound' : 'Inbound'
$_.Direction = ('Outbound', 'Inbound')[$_.Direction -eq '%%14592']
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works like a charm. if I wanted to add the date when each blocked event was created, how would I do that? just to point me to the right direction. because I don't see the date being mentioned in the output but it should be called `TimeCreated` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74988532/20682592). so is it even possible to add `TimeCreated` as a new property there in the XML input?

Comment: @Jameschad, presumably, the following works; if it doesn't, please ask a new question. In lieu of `foreach { $hash = @{ } } { $hash[$_.name] = $_.'#text' } { [pscustomobject]$hash }`, use `foreach { $hash = @{ TimeCreated = [datetime] $xml.Event.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime } } { $hash[$_.name] = $_.'#text' } { [pscustomobject]$hash }`

Comment: Thank you again, just want to confirm that it does indeed work and successfully adds `TimeCreated` as a new property.